# Как вычислять ошибки в анимации?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animation, 3d

[Здесь код!](https://codesandbox.io/s/xlkmjl0z7o?hidenavigation=1)

Сверху окошка с выводом результата есть кнопка "открыть в новом окне". Лучше нажмите на нее, так все будет понятнее.

Есть 3Д куб. вы можете двигать его с помощью кнопок нумпада (2, 4, 8, 6).

Если вы будете долго играться с анимацией, удерживать 2 кнопки одновременно, быстро менять направления, отпускать и нажимать кнопки в разном порядке (в консоли можно смотреть), то в конечном итоге заметите, что куб иногда дёргается. Меня это тревожит, потому что я не могу это исправить. Есть такая теория:

1. Куб изменяет свои css параметры rotateX и rotateY.
2. Эти значения задаются кубу с помощью одноимённых переменных.
3. Возможно такое, что кода одна из переменных долго не меняетеся, а потом резко должна примениться к кубу, то из за разницы ее предыдущего значения, и только что созданного, а так же из за зависимости между rotateX и rotateY - происходят какие то дикие выворачивания.

Может быть расписал не очень понятно, но, может, кто-нибудь с такой проблемой уже сталкивался и сможет помочь/объяснить?

Comment: А надо ли чтобы обработчик вызывались тогда, когда нажато больше одной клавиши?

Comment: Да, что бы можно было крутить куб сразу по двум осям. (Наискосок)

Answer (score 0):

Запретите одновременное вращение в противоположных направлениях.